# How to deserialize the json object response retrieve from api for large data

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, deserialization, multipartform-data, json-deserialization

While deserializing the json object, it is throwing exception as "Array dimensions exceeded supported range" for large byte array

below is my code to get the response and deserialize the object

```
Dictionary<string, object> postParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
postParameters.Add("JOB_ID", Obj.Ref_Job_ID.ToString());
postParameters.Add("Org_Id", Obj.Org_Id);
// Create request and receive response
string postURL = "http://localhost:61792/getOutputFileDetails";
string userAgent = "xxx";
HttpWebResponse webResponse = FormUpload.MultipartFormDataPost(postURL, userAgent, postParameters);
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
string fullResponse = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
webResponse.Close();
List<Publishing> objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Publishing>>(fullResponse);

public static HttpWebResponse MultipartFormDataPost(string postUrl, string userAgent, Dictionary<string, object> postParameters)
        {            
            byte[] formData = GetMultipartFormData(postParameters, formDataBoundary);

            return PostForm(postUrl, userAgent, contentType, formData);
        }
private static HttpWebResponse PostForm(string postUrl, string userAgent, string contentType, byte[] formData)
        {                                   
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = contentType;
            request.UserAgent = userAgent;
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.ContentLength = formData.Length;                        
            // Send the form data to the request.
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }           
            return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;           
        }
```

Deserailizing properly for below 300 mb file content, but for more that it is exception throwing